# Call yield put() inside a success callback

Tags: reactjs, redux, yield, amazon-cognito, redux-saga

I am brand new to React and Redux.

I am using react-redux to call the AWS Cognito service which takes an object containing a success and failure callback. I get my JWT back from AWS Cognito when I console.log inside my success callback; however, how can I `yield put()` inside this callback since it's not a generator function (`function*`).

## Here's some code:

```
export function* getAWSToken(){
  // username, password and userPool come from react state
  // not showing code for brevity.

  const userData = {
      Username: username,
      Pool: userPool,
    };
  const authenticationData = {
    Username : username,
    Password : password,
  };

  const cognitoUser = new AWSCognito.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.CognitoUser(userData);
  const authenticationDetails = new AWSCognito.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.AuthenticationDetails(authenticationData);

  // This here is the callback
  cognitoUser.authenticateUser(authenticationDetails, {
    onSuccess(result){
      yield put(cognitoTokenObtained(result.getIdToken().getJwtToken())
    },
    onFailure(err){}
  });
}
```

Comment: Why use a generator function? If each time you call `getAWSToken`, cognito gives you a new token, does a generator improve things?

Comment: As prefaced, I'm super new to React and Redux, so I'm following examples. It appears that wherever redux-saga is used, a generator function is used. If this isn't the case, then please inform.

Comment: Hmm, it seems overly complex to me. You could just use a normal function, pass in a callback to `getAWSToken(yourCallback)` and then call that function inside `onSuccess` like `callback(result)`. But if there's some `redux-saga`-specific reason for using generator functions, then I wouldn't want to suggest something that breaks `redux-saga`.

Comment: Why are you saying you can't use `yield` in your callback ? Have you any error ? Because the callback is not a generator but your `getAWSToken` is, so you shouldn't have any issue with the `yield` here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using redux-saga (which is awesome), you can use the [call effect](https://yelouafi.github.io/redux-saga/docs/basics/DeclarativeEffects.html) to transform an asyc callback like cognitoUser.authenticateUser into a set of instructions to be executed by the middlewhere.

When the middleware resolves the call it will step through the generator to the next yield statement, you can assign the return result to a variable that you can then place in your state using a put effect.

```
export function* getAWSToken(){
  // username, password and userPool come from react state
  // not showing code for brevity.

  const userData = {
      Username: username,
      Pool: userPool,
    };
  const authenticationData = {
    Username : username,
    Password : password,
  };

  const cognitoUser = new AWSCognito.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.CognitoUser(userData);
  const authenticationDetails = new AWSCognito.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.AuthenticationDetails(authenticationData);

  // Note: since you're invoking an object method
  // you'll want to pass the object's context (this) with the call via an array

  const token = yield apply(cognitoUser, cognitoUser.authenticateUser, [authenticationDetails, { onSuccess(response){return response}, onFailure(){} }]);

  yield put(cognitoTokenObtained(token.getIdToken().getJwtToken());
}
```

There's also [this incredible tutorial](http://yelouafi.github.io/redux-saga/docs/introduction/BeginnerTutorial.html) I'd highly recommend.

Edit: You left out some code for brevity, but I'd highly recommend wrapping the code inside the generator in try catches since you're depending on external IO from an API.

Comment: Thank you for your example and tutorial link, I've learned more about `call/put` then I had known beforehand; however, I am still having a slight issue with the example you provided. When I use call for `cognitoUser.authenticateUser`, the AWS cognito JS library complains with `TypeError: Cannot read property 'getUserPoolId' of undefined`, which leads me to think I am not passing the params properly into the `call()` method.

Comment: Figured it out, I needed to pass the context in, i.e., cognitoUser. So, my call looks like this. `const token = yield call([cognitoUser, cognitoUser.authenticateUser], authenticationDetails);`

Comment: Ah! Sorry I missed that! I'll update the answer for future viewers. Thanks Patrick!

Comment: One more thing. This AWS call wants access to the context of authenticationDetails (which is passed as the params). Can I pass that context as well? BTW, you can use `apply(context, fn, args)` instead of `call([context, fn], args)`

Comment: authenticationDetails itself is a context (a context is an object). You have to pass them separately in the API call because call builds a definition of the method call into a function w/ no knowledge of the instance itself. Is it giving you a helpful error at all?

Comment: By calling with apply, rather than call, which takes the first param as context, I got it working; however, the code isn't yielding. I `console.log` right after `const token` and get `undefined`, then the `console.log` I put into the `onSuccess` callback fires.

Comment: the onSuccess callback you're passing as an argument doesn't return anything, what if you try the above? I just edited it if it looks really similar

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/119038/discussion-between-patrick-robert-shea-oconnor-and-the-brofessor).

Comment: The tutorial has been moved to https://redux-saga.github.io/redux-saga/docs/introduction/BeginnerTutorial.html